# SPF record - does not designate permitted sender hosts

Tags: smtp, phpmailer, spam, spam-prevention, spf

I have a GoDaddy Office 365 email account test@mydomain.com and am using PHPMailer to send out emails using SMTP.

Emails are hitting spam folders whenever my script sends them out, in the headers I can see the following message...

```
Received-SPF: None (protection.outlook.com: mydomain.com does not
 designate permitted sender hosts)
```

The script is running from another domain mydomain2.com, I have 2 SPF records on mydomain.com set up that look like this...

```
v=spf1 include:spf.protection.outlook.com -all
v=spf1 include:mydomain2.com -all
```

Where am I going wrong?  Do the records need to merged?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Yes, they do need to be merged. Merging those would look like this:

```
v=spf1 include:spf.protection.outlook.com include:mydomain2.com -all
```

Are you sure that's what you mean though? `include:mydomain2.com` does not mean "allow sending from mydomain2.com"; it means "allow sending from the servers listed in the SPF record for mydomain2.com", which may be entirely different. It wouldn't surprise me if you needed to add an `a` clause, or possibly an `mx` instead of that `include`, but I can't tell from the info you've posted.

Update - to simply designate the host that the domain points at as a sending host, and also the inbound mail server for your domain, do this instead:

```
v=spf1 a mx include:spf.protection.outlook.com -all
```

Comment: Yep thats exactly what I am trying to do 'allow sending from mydomain2.com' - Explains why things aren't working now

Comment: Is this SPF record to be updated on mydomain.com rather than mydomain2.com?

Comment: It should be on whatever domain your from address is using, so if it's `test@mydomain.com`, it would be in the SPF record for `mydomain.com`.

Comment: this tool is the spiffiest for creating an SPF https://www.spfwizard.net/ I would create both an SPF and TXT records for the domain sending the emails. Can test your SPF here https://www.kitterman.com/spf/validate.html

Comment: Don’t bother creating SPF-type records. They are often not supported by DNS services, and are now deprecated anyway; stick to TXT type records.